# In Spring security 2.0.2 How to redirect to a requested url after login

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, login-control

In my application i am sending an email to a user with a link to a jsp. if user clicks on the link and is not logged-in then it is redirecting to the login page and after successfully login it is redirecting to the default landing page.

I want when user logged in successfully then it should be redirect to same page (link page) for which user submitted the request and not to the default page.

I am using Spring Security 2.0.2.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

define yourAuthenticationFilter  with SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
    <bean id="yourAuthenticationFilter" class="yourAuthenticationFilterClass">  
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: sorry I did not realized that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. i have added the following lines in custom authentication filter which extends `AuthenticationProcessingFilter`

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        SavedRequest savedRequest = null; 
        if (session != null) {
            savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);
        }
```

and savedRequest object stores the last requested url and which can be set as a target url after successful authentication.

P.S. This work in Spring security 2.0.